# VS 2013 Slow Text Editor On One .CS File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am asking this here in hope to get a response from developers...as I have searched the web and cant find anything.

I currently have a windows service in Visual Studio 2013. The project runs fine and I am able to use VS without any problems. When I open one specific file the text editor becomes very slow, intelli sense, auto-complete are all very slow only with the one .cs file. Switching back to any other .cs file then the text editor works as expected.

Why does the text editor become slow with just this one file and how do I fix it? There is only about 1000 lines of code and the most complex thing in the .cs file is a Parallel foreach loop

Possibly the parsing of the document that takes long?!

EDIT:

It seems like the Parallel.ForEach causes the slowness of the editor. If I replace the Parallel.ForEach with a normal foreach then I have no problems.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
//Get all required nodes          
IEnumerable<XElement> childElements = from el in StreamRootChildDoc(fi.FullName, "PortfolioValuationsBranch") select el;
XNamespace ns = "http://www.namespacename.co.za/namespace";

ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1; //Max Parallel inserts

Parallel.ForEach(childElements, options, element =>
{
    string BranchCode = element.Element(ns + "Branch").Element(ns + "BrnCde").Value;
    string BranchName = element.Element(ns + "Branch").Element(ns + "Name").Value;
    string BranchAfrName = element.Element(ns + "Branch").Element(ns + "AfrName").Value;

    IEnumerable<XElement> Partners = StreamRootChildDocString(element.ToString(), "PortfolioValuationsPartner");
    foreach(XElement pElement in Partners)
    {
    //Parallel.ForEach(Partners, options, pElement =>
    //{
        string PartnerCode = pElement.Element(ns + "Partner").Element(ns + "ParCde").Value;
        string PartnerName = pElement.Element(ns + "Partner").Element(ns + "Name").Value;

        IEnumerable<XElement> Advisors = StreamRootChildDocString(pElement.ToString(), "PortfolioValuationsAdvisor");
        foreach(XElement aElement in Advisors)
        {
        //Parallel.ForEach(Advisors, options, aElement =>
        //{
            string AdvisorCode = aElement.Element(ns + "Advisor").Element(ns + "AdvrCde").Value;
            string AdvisorName = aElement.Element(ns + "Advisor").Element(ns + "Name").Value;

            IEnumerable<XElement> Clients = StreamRootChildDocString(aElement.ToString(), "PortfolioValuationsClient");
            foreach(XElement cElement in Clients)
            {
            //Parallel.ForEach(Clients, options, cElement =>
            //{
                IEnumerable<XElement> ClientNode = StreamRootChildDocString(cElement.ToString(), "Client");
                string sID = (string)BuildClientID(BrokerCode);
                string ClientCode = ClientNode.Select(x => (String)x.Element(ns + "ClntCde")).First();

                PVClientTbl ClientData = ClientNode.Select(x => new PVClientTbl
                {
                    ID = sID,
                    BrokerCode = BrokerCode,
                    StatementDate = FileMonthEndDate,
                    BrokerName = BrokerName,
                    BranchCode = BranchCode,
                    PartnerCode = PartnerCode,
                    AdvisorCode = AdvisorCode,
                    ClientCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "ClntCde"),
                    Title = (String)x.Element(ns + "Title"),
                    Initials = (String)x.Element(ns + "Initials"),
                    Surname = (String)x.Element(ns + "Surname"),
                    IDNumber = null,
                    ManagementCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "ManCde"),
                    Address1 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr1"),
                    Address2 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr2"),
                    Address3 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr3"),
                    Address4 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr4"),
                    PostalCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "PostCde"),
                    NonRes = null,
                    Facsimile = null,
                    Email = (String)x.Element(ns + "Emailadr"),
                    ElectronicIndicator = (String)x.Element(ns + "ElecInd"),
                    Language = (String)x.Element(ns + "Lang"),
                    TelNo1 = (String)x.Element(ns + "TelNo1"),
                }).First();

                bool bDidInsert = DAL.DigiLoaderDAL.CreatePortfolioClient(ClientData);
                if (bDidInsert)
                {
                    IEnumerable<XElement> HoldingTypeNode = StreamRootChildDocString(cElement.ToString(), "HoldingType");

                    foreach (XElement htElement in HoldingTypeNode)
                    {
                        string HoldingTypeDescription = (String)htElement.Element(ns + "Desc");
                        IEnumerable<XElement> HoldingSectorNode = StreamRootChildDocString(cElement.ToString(), "HoldingSector");

                        foreach (XElement hsElement in HoldingSectorNode)
                        {
                            string HoldingSectorDescription = (String)hsElement.Element(ns + "Desc");

                            List<HoldingsTbl> HoldingLineData = htElement.Descendants(ns + "HoldingLine").Select(x => new HoldingsTbl
                            {
                                ID = sID,
                                PVDate = null,
                                Type = HoldingTypeDescription,
                                Sector = "",
                                InstrumentAlpha = (String)x.Element(ns + "Instrmnt").Element(ns + "InstrAlpha"),
                                InstrumentName = (String)x.Element(ns + "Instrmnt").Element(ns + "Name"),
                                PriceFormat = (String)x.Element(ns + "PrceFormat"),
                                Movement = (String)x.Element(ns + "MoveQty"),
                                QuantityHeld = (String)x.Element(ns + "QtyHeld"),
                                CostEach = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostEach"),
                                CostTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotal"),
                                CurrentEach = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrEach"),
                                CurrentTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotal"),
                                Percentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "PFVPerc"),
                                DividendEach = (String)x.Element(ns + "DividendEach"),
                                DividendTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "DividendTotal"),
                                YieldPercentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "YieldPerc"),
                                EarningsPerShare = (String)x.Element(ns + "EarningsPerShare"),
                                ApprDepr = (String)x.Element(ns + "ApprDeprAmt"),
                                GiltsAmount = (String)x.Element(ns + "GiltsAmt"),
                                CleanPriceEach = (String)x.Element(ns + "CleanPrceEach"),
                                AccuredInterest = (String)x.Element(ns + "AccruedInterest"),
                                Seq = x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() + 1,

                            }).ToList();

                            DAL.DigiLoaderDAL.CreatePVHoldings(HoldingLineData);

                            List<HoldingSectorAnalysisTbl> HoldingSectorAnalysisData = htElement.Descendants(ns + "HoldingSectorAnalysis").Select(x => new HoldingSectorAnalysisTbl
                            {
                                ID = sID,
                                Type = HoldingSectorDescription,
                                Sector = "",
                                CostTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotal"),
                                CurrentTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotal"),
                                Percentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "PFVPerc"),
                                DividendTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "DividendTotal"),
                                YieldPercentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "YieldPerc"),
                                ApprDepr = (String)x.Element(ns + "ApprDeprAmt"),
                                Seq = x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() + 1,

                            }).ToList();

                            //write to SQL
                            DAL.DigiLoaderDAL.CreatePVHoldingSectorAnalysis(HoldingSectorAnalysisData);
                        }

                        //HoldingTypeAnalysis
                        List<HoldingTypeAnalysisTbl> HoldingTypeAnalysisData = htElement.Descendants(ns + "HoldingTypeAnalysis").Select(x => new HoldingTypeAnalysisTbl
                        {
                            ID = sID,
                            CostTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotal"),
                            CurrentTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotal"),
                            Percentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "PFVPerc"),
                            DividendTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "DividendTotal"),
                            YieldPercentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "YieldPerc"),
                            ApprDepr = (String)x.Element(ns + "ApprDeprAmt"),
                            Seq = x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() + 1,

                        }).ToList();

                        //write to SQL
                        DAL.DigiLoaderDAL.CreatePVHoldingTypeAnalysis(HoldingTypeAnalysisData);
                    }

                    //cash detail
                    List<CashDetailTbl> CashDetailData = cElement.Descendants(ns + "CashDetail").Select(x => new CashDetailTbl
                    {
                        ID = sID,
                        Description = (String)x.Element(ns + "Desc"),
                        Amount = (String)x.Element(ns + "Amt"),
                        Percentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "CashPerc"),
                        Seq = x.ElementsBeforeSelf(ns + "CashDetail").Count() + 1,

                    }).ToList();
                    DAL.DigiLoaderDAL.CreatePVCashDetail(CashDetailData);

                    List<AnalysisTbl> AnalysisData = cElement.Descendants(ns + "PFVAnalysis").Select(x => new AnalysisTbl
                    {
                        ID = sID,
                        CostTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotal"),
                        CostTotalInclCash = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotalInclCash"),
                        CurrTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotal"),
                        CurrTotalInclCash = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotalInclCash"),
                        CashAmount = (String)x.Element(ns + "CashAmt"),
                        Percentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "PFVPerc"),
                        DividendTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "DividendTotal"),
                        YieldPercentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "YieldPerc"),
                        ApprDepr = (String)x.Element(ns + "ApprDeprAmt")

                    }).ToList();
                    //sql insert                    

                    List<ProfitLossTbl> ProfitLossData = cElement.Descendants(ns + "ProfitLoss").Select(x => new ProfitLossTbl
                    {
                        ID = sID,
                        Description = (String)x.Element(ns + "Desc"),
                        Amount = (String)x.Element(ns + "Amt"),
                    }).ToList();
                    //sql insert

                    List<HistoricTbl> HistoricData = cElement.Descendants(ns + "HistoricalComparison").Select(x => new HistoricTbl
                    {
                        ID = sID,
                        Date = (String)x.Element(ns + "Date"),
                        CostTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotal"),
                        CostTotalInclCash = (String)x.Element(ns + "CostTotalInclCash"),
                        CurrTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotal"),
                        CurrTotalInclCash = (String)x.Element(ns + "CurrTotalInclCash"),
                        CashAmount = (String)x.Element(ns + "CashAmt"),
                        DividendTotal = (String)x.Element(ns + "DividendTotal"),
                        YieldPercentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "YieldPerc"),
                        ApprDepr = (String)x.Element(ns + "ApprDeprAmt"),

                    }).ToList();
                    //sql insert

                    List<AssetAllocationTbl> AssetAllocationData = cElement.Descendants(ns + "AssetAllocation").Select(x => new AssetAllocationTbl
                    {
                        ID = sID,
                        Description = (String)x.Element(ns + "Desc"),
                        Amount = (String)x.Element(ns + "Amt"),
                        Percentage = (String)x.Element(ns + "PFVPerc")
                    }).ToList();
                    //sql insert

                    List<PVCopiesTbl> PvCopiesData = cElement.Descendants(ns + "AssetAllocation").Select(x => new PVCopiesTbl
                    {
                        ID = sID,
                        BrokerCode = BrokerCode,
                        StatementDate = FileMonthEndDate,
                        BranchCode = BranchCode,
                        PartnerCode = PartnerCode,
                        AdvisorCode = AdvisorCode,
                        ClientCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "ClntCde"),
                        Title = (String)x.Element(ns + "Title"),
                        Initials = (String)x.Element(ns + "Initials"),
                        Surname = (String)x.Element(ns + "Surname"),
                        IDNumber = null,
                        ManagementCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "ManCde"),
                        Address1 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr1"),
                        Address2 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr2"),
                        Address3 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr3"),
                        Address4 = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "Addr4"),
                        PostalCode = (String)x.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "PostCde"),
                        NonRes = null,
                        Facsimile = null,
                        Email = (String)x.Element(ns + "Emailadr"),
                        ElectronicIndicator = (String)x.Element(ns + "ElecInd"),
                        Language = (String)x.Element(ns + "Lang"),
                        TelNo1 = (String)x.Element(ns + "TelNo1"),
                        NumberOfCopies = (String)x.Element(ns + "NumberOfCopies")

                    }).ToList();
                    //sql insert
                    //DAL.DigiLoaderDAL.CreateRec
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: did not insert client row");
                }
            }//);
        }//);
    }//);
});
```

Comment: Got any addins running (e.g. Resharper)? If so, try disabling them temporarily in case it's one of those.

Comment: No Addins except for TFS power tools

Comment: And if you disable TFS power tools it's the same?

Comment: Do you use a lot of namespaces in that file compared with the others?  It could be that it is pulling in a lot of different namespaces, causing it to slow down a bit.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out bits of the code to narrow things down ?

Comment: Does this happen on anyone else' PC ? What about previous versions of VS ?

Comment: I tried with VS 2013 and VS2012 and had issues in both. Running on a virtual machine with Quad 2.90 GHz Intel Xeon(R)E5-2690 with 4 virtual processors and 8192MB RAM (this is my dev machine-production will have more-a lot more)

Comment: well, for what it's worth, i cut and pasted your code in a VS2013 project and didn't have any issues. You might want to try running VS with /Log and /SafeMode switches (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) and report it as a bug to MS.